# Anchore Engine - Jenkins CI plugin

Tags: security, docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, docker-image

We are trying to scan our docker images using Anchore Engine Jenkins plugin.

Currently we create our application docker images, push it in our own private local registry and then deploy it in our test environments.

Now, we want to setup docker image scanning in our CI/CD process to check for any vulnerabilities.

We have installed Anchore Engine using the recommended Docker-Compose yaml method given in the Documentation link:
https://anchore.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/36000020729-install-on-docker-swarm

Post installation, we installed the
Anchore Container Image Scanner Plugin in Jenkins.

We configured the plugin as mentioned in the document link:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Anchore+Container+Image+Scanner+Plugin

However, the scanning fails. Error Message as follows:

```
2018-10-11T07:01:44.647 INFO   AnchoreWorker   Analysis request accepted, received image digest sha256:7d6fb7e5e7a74a4309cc436f6d11c29a96cbf27a4a8cb45a50cb0a326dc32fe8
2018-10-11T07:01:44.647 INFO   AnchoreWorker   Waiting for analysis of 10.180.25.2:5000/hello-world:latest, polling status periodically
2018-10-11T07:01:44.647 DEBUG  AnchoreWorker   anchore-engine get policy evaluation URL: http://10.180.25.2:8228/v1/images/sha256:7d6fb7e5e7a74a4309cc436f6d11c29a96cbf27a4a8cb45a50cb0a326dc32fe8/check?tag=10.180.25.2:5000/hello-world:latest&detail=true
2018-10-11T07:01:44.648 DEBUG  AnchoreWorker   Attempting anchore-engine get policy evaluation (1/300)
2018-10-11T07:01:44.675 DEBUG  AnchoreWorker   anchore-engine get policy evaluation failed. URL: http://10.180.25.2:8228/v1/images/sha256:7d6fb7e5e7a74a4309cc436f6d11c29a96cbf27a4a8cb45a50cb0a326dc32fe8/check?tag=10.180.25.2:5000/hello-world:latest&detail=true, status: HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND, error: {
  "detail": {}, 
  "httpcode": 404, 
  "message": "image is not analyzed - analysis_status: not_analyzed"
}
```

NOTE:
In Image TAG `10.180.25.2:5000/hello-world:latest`, `10.180.25.2:5000` is our local private registry and `hello-world:latest` is latest hello-world image available in docker hub which we pulled and pushed in our registry to try out image scanning using Anchore-Engine.

Unfortunately we are not able to find much resource online to try and resolve the above mentioned issue.

Anyone who might have worked on Anchore-Engine, please may I request to have a look and help us resolve this issue.

Also, any suggestions or alternatives to anchore-engine or detailed steps in case we might have missed anything would be really appreciated.

**End of the output is as follows:**

```
2018-10-15T00:48:43.880 WARN AnchoreWorker anchore-engine get policy evaluation failed. HTTP method: GET, URL: http://10.180.25.2:8228/v1/images/sha256:7d6fb7e5e7a74a4309cc436f6d11c29a96cbf27a4a8cb45a50cb0a326dc32fe8/check?tag=10.180.25.2:5000/hello-world:latest&detail=true, status: 404, error: {
"detail": {},
"httpcode": 404,
"message": "image is not analyzed - analysis_status: not_analyzed"
}

2018-10-15T00:48:43.880 WARN AnchoreWorker Exhausted all attempts polling anchore-engine. Analysis is incomplete for sha256:7d6fb7e5e7a74a4309cc436f6d11c29a96cbf27a4a8cb45a50cb0a326dc32fe8
2018-10-15T00:48:43.880 ERROR AnchorePlugin Failing Anchore Container Image Scanner Plugin step due to errors in plugin execution
hudson.AbortException: Timed out waiting for anchore-engine analysis to complete (increasing engineRetries might help). Check above logs for errors from anchore-engine
at com.anchore.jenkins.plugins.anchore.BuildWorker.runGatesEngine(BuildWorker.java:480)
at com.anchore.jenkins.plugins.anchore.BuildWorker.runGates(BuildWorker.java:343)
at com.anchore.jenkins.plugins.anchore.AnchoreBuilder.perform(AnchoreBuilder.java:338)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
```

**I also checked status and found below:**

```
docker run anchore/engine-cli:latest anchore-cli --u admin --p admin123 --url http://172.18.0.1:8228/v1 system status
Service analyzer (dockerhostid-anchore-engine, http://anchore-engine:8084): up
Service catalog (dockerhostid-anchore-engine, http://anchore-engine:8082): up
Service policy_engine (dockerhostid-anchore-engine, http://anchore-engine:8087): down (unavailable)
Service simplequeue (dockerhostid-anchore-engine, http://anchore-engine:8083): up
Service apiext (dockerhostid-anchore-engine, http://anchore-engine:8228): up
Service kubernetes_webhook (dockerhostid-anchore-engine, http://anchore-engine:8338): up
```

Engine DB Version: 0.0.7
Engine Code Version: 0.2.4

It seems service policy engine is down

Service policy_engine (dockerhostid-anchore-engine, http://anchore-engine:8087): down (unavailable)

**I also checked the docker logs . I found below error:**

```
[service:policy_engine] 2018-10-15 09:37:46+0000 [-] [bootstrap] [DEBUG] service (policy_engine) starting in: 4
[service:policy_engine] 2018-10-15 09:37:46+0000 [-] [bootstrap] [INFO] Registration complete.
[service:policy_engine] 2018-10-15 09:37:46+0000 [-] [bootstrap] [INFO] Checking feeds client credentials
[service:policy_engine] 2018-10-15 09:37:46+0000 [-] [bootstrap] [DEBUG] Initializing a feeds client
[service:policy_engine] 2018-10-15 09:37:47+0000 [-] [bootstrap] [DEBUG] init values: [None, None, None, (), None, None]
[service:policy_engine] 2018-10-15 09:37:47+0000 [-] [bootstrap] [DEBUG] using values: ['https://ancho.re/v1/service/feeds', 'https://ancho.re/oauth/token', 'https://ancho.re/v1/account/users', 'anon@ancho.re', 3, 60]
[service:policy_engine] 2018-10-15 09:37:47+0000 [-] [urllib3.connectionpool] [DEBUG] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): ancho.re
[service:policy_engine] 2018-10-15 09:37:50+0000 [-] [bootstrap] [ERROR] Preflight checks failed with error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ancho.re', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/account/users/anon@ancho.re (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ffa905f0b90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',)). Aborting service startup
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/anchore_manager/cli/service.py", line 158, in startup_service
   raise Exception("process exited: " + str(rc))
Exception: process exited: 1
[anchore-policy-engine] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO] service process exited at (Mon Oct 15 09:37:50 2018): process exited: 1
[anchore-policy-engine] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO] exiting service thread
```

Thanks and Regards,

Rohan Shetty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have resolved the issue.

**Root Cause:**

We were not able to establish a successful https connection to URL : https://ancho.re from within the anchore-engine docker container.
As a result the service:policy_engine was not able to start.

https://ancho.re is required to download policy feeds and sync-up periodically. Without these policy anchore-engine won't be able to analyse the docker images.

**Solution:**

1) We passed a HTTPS_PROXY URL as an environment variable in the docker-compose.yaml of anchore-engine.

We used this proxy URL to bypass restrictions in our environment and establish a connection with https://ancho.re url.

2) Restarted the docker containers.

Finally we got all services up and running including Anchore policy-engine.

FYI:
It takes a while to download all the required Feeds depending on your internet speed.

Lastly, Thanks to the Anchore community for quick responses and support over slack.

Hope this helps.

**Warm Regards,**

**Rohan Shetty**

Answer (score 0):

When images are added to anchore-engine, they are queued for analysis which moves them through a simple state machine that starts with ‘not_analyzed’, goes to ‘analyzing’ and finally ends in either ‘analyzed’ or ‘analysis_failed’.  Only when an image has reached ‘analyzed’ will a policy evaluation be possible.

The anchore Jenkins plugin will add an image, then poll the engine for image status/evaluation for the configured number of tries (default 300).  Once the image goes to ‘analyzed’ (where policy evaluation is possible), the plugin will then receive a policy evaluation result from the engine.

The plugin will fail the build (by default) if the max retries has been performed and the image has not reached ‘analyzed’, if the image does reach ‘analyzed’ but the policy evaluation is producing a ‘fail’ result (meaning the image didn’t pass your configured policy checks).  Note that all build failure behavior can be controlled in the plugin (I.e. there are options to allow the plugin to succeed even if the analysis or image eval fails).

You’ll need to look at the end of the output from your build run (instead of just the beginning from your post), and combined with the information above, it should be clear which scenario is causing the plugin to fail the build.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel
I have updated my question with more information

Comment: How do I increase increasing engineRetries?